# mysql's ORDER BY FIELD equivalent in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 5.2. Is there a parameter that let you sort the order of the returned result by the specific field value? For example, in `mysql` I use `ORDER BY FIELD` to sort the result in specific order:

```
SELECT id,txt FROM `review`
order by FIELD(a.id,2,3,5,7) ;
```

I have read the `sort` section in the [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter) but it doesn't seem to have any mention of a similar parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Solr can do exactly what you want. The closest you might get is a range query. A range query looks like this:

`your_field:[valueA TO valueB]`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve custom sort in solr using `^=`

Locate **Constant Score with ^=** in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser

```
q=id:(2^=4 3^=3 5^=2 7^=1)
```

You can run

```
array = [2,3,5,7]
var string = "q=id:(";
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  string += array[i]+"^=" + (array.length-i) + " ";
}
string+=")";
// string => q=id:(2^=4 3^=3 5^=2 7^=1)
```